# Distinct values of column using case when based on conditions of other columns

Tags: sql, join, if-statement

I have two tables that have one field in common (acct #).  Table1 has distinct values of acct # and table2 has Volume sold by acct # by day over a 2 year period.  I'm essentially trying to do a a sumif lookup from table2 to table1 and sum up Volume if Volume is within a certain date [DeliveryDateSk], which is included in table2.

Now I can use the same table for both table1 and table2.  My sql for table1 would be:

```
SELECT
left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7) as [Acct #]
FROM [dbo].[FactActualDetail] [FactActualDetail]
GROUP BY left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7)
```

Table2 has already been broked down and I have grouped all Product by day, eliminated any product lines that contained an 0 in the [EQMultiplier] column of the table, and am only showing [DeliveryDateSk] > 20110102.  I've also joined with another table (DimCustomer) to show me only customers with [SC] = 4 or 5 or 6 or 7.  I need to do this sql to reduce the number of rows and just show me Volume by day by acct.

```
SELECT 
sum([FactActualDetail].[Volume]) AS [Volume],
sum([FactActualDetail].[GrossMargin]) AS [GrossMargin],
left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7) as [Acct #],
[FactActualDetail].[DeliveryDateSK] AS [DeliveryDateSK]

FROM [dbo].[FactActualDetail] [FactActualDetail]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] [DimCustomer] ON ([FactActualDetail].[CustomerSK]
= [DimCustomer].[CustomerSK])

WHERE [EQMultiplier] > 0 AND [DeliveryDateSK] > 20110102 AND ([SC] = 04 OR [SC]
= 05 OR [SC] = 06 OR [SC] = 07)

GROUP BY left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7),[DeliveryDateSK]
```

So the result of the above code returns me Table2 that looks like this:

```
| Volume | GrossMargin  | Acct #  |  DeliveryDateSk | 
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    5   |      35      | 5551111 |     20110101    |  
|    3   |      15      | 5551111 |     20110105    |  
|    6   |      40      | 5551112 |     20110101    |  
|    2   |      11      | 5551112 |     20110109    |  
|    1   |       9      | 5551112 |     20110110    |  
|    9   |      77      | 5551113 |     20110102    |  
|    8   |      74      | 5551114 |     20110104    |
```

What I want to now do is join table2 with table1 that contains a distinct list of Acct #'s.  With table1, I will need to write a code for a column that will return me Volume if [DeliveryDateSk] is during week 1 of this year.  I will then write statement to return me Volume for [DeliveryDateSk] for the prior 52 weeks of the 1st code that I wrote.  Statements will look something like this:

```
sum(CASE WHEN ([DeliveryDateSK] >= 20120102 AND [DeliveryDateSk] <= 20120108)
AND [FactActualDetail].[CaseAndGallonVolume] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS 
[Week1 2012]

sum(CASE WHEN ([DeliveryDateSK] >= 20110103 AND [DeliveryDateSk] <= 20120101) 
AND [FactActualDetail].[CaseAndGallonVolume] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS [2011]
```

The idea is if an account had Volume during Week 1 of this year and didn't have Volume during prior 52 weeks, then it's an NEW account and will need to be noted as that (a simple "1" in that column would be suffice for Week 1).  I will then need to repeat the above statements for the following 51 weeks.  So if an account had Volume during week 2 of 2012 (between [DeliveryDateSK] of 20120109 and 20120115) and didn't have Volume during the prior 52 weeks (Week 2 of 2011 to Week 1 of 2012, or more precise - 20110110 and 20120108), then I would note it as an "2".  So you can imagine one long code!

I'm picturing a sql statement along the lines of:

```
sum(CASE WHEN ((([DeliveryDateSK] >= 20120102 AND [DeliveryDateSk] <= 20120108) AND
[FactActualDetail].[Volume] > 0) AND (([DeliveryDateSK] >= 20110103 AND     
[DeliveryDateSk] <= 20120101) AND [FactActualDetail].[Volume] < 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)
AS [Week 1 NEW]
```

That should return me a 1 if the Acct is a New acct.  Then I would repeat the code and do ELSEIF for Week 2, and so on until 52.  My output would only have two columns: Acct # and my column of the long code, which would have values from 1 to 52 if they have met the condition.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would consider going a slightly different route: use a 64bit integer and use each bit for each week of the year (two of them in your case -- one for last year, one for this year) you then do an aggregate SUM across each of the 52 weeks.  In the end, records with exact values of 1, 2, 4, ....2^n will be new accounts.  You can use DATEPART to get the week of the year, which can then be used for 2^(DATEPART week) to know which bit to set.  You then have a single row per account with proper bits set, so you can easily run a calculation.  It should also be pretty efficient (numeric bit checking)

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @ Eli - thanks for the response, unforunately I'm a newbie at sql and not sure how to use 64bit integer. Are you meaning have 52 columns for each week then 52 columns for the years that I need?

Comment: @ Gordon - just using SQL Server, using databases from my Company with house customer information

Comment: @Dale . . . and what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Dale . . .It would actually help if you would describe what your ultimate goal is.  For instance, why not just have a date that is the "new" date for each account (or more than one, since that is possible in a two-year period)?

Comment: @ Gordon - I believe we use Enterprise. I'm doing the SQL in Powerpivot since I'm pulling multiple tables in. My goal is I need to signify whether or not an account classifies as NEW based on the criteria as I do this report every week. I'd like to automate it and I'm close to getting it but not quite there. Also if an account is NEW it can only be listed once between weeks 1 and 52.